# Scope Issue with setInterval Game Loop

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

I'm building a game with simple code, yet wieldy, and I've run into an issue.

My game loop looks like this:

```
function loop() {

    updateGame(game1, canvas1, onInit);
    displayGame(game1, canvas2, onInit);
    monitorPreformance(game1, canvas3, onInit);
    onInit = false;
}
setInterval(loop, 20);
```

And, for example, I have inside updateGame:

```
function updateGame(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    var a, b, c;
    function doThis {
        //
    }
    function doThat {
        //
    }
    function draw(){
        doThis();
        doThat();
    }
    draw();
}
```

The issue is that my variables a, b and c, get reinitialized each time I call setInterval. When the game was created, I called setInterval three times in each updateGame, drawGame, and monitorPreformance. Now I want to be able to do things like pause the game, and so I'd like to set it up as above, but it causes these scope issues.

Is there an easy fix? Do I have to initialize a global object to contain a, b, c for each function? Note that there are about fifty such variables and this would require a semi major rewrite of the code. Note that some of the variables are required to be passed between the three games, and so are parameters of game1. However, other variables just need to presist between the looped calls of each function.

If there is no easy fix, what is the correct approach?

Comment: Maybe you should pass it as parameter, maybe they should be `game1` properties, maybe they should be global variables. It is hard to know without knowing the details of your scenario.

Comment: You can make this variable global. `var window.a;` etc

Comment: Ignore the global variable recommendation

Comment: The module suggestion was a perfect fit for my design.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achive this is to use Module Pattern:

```
var updateGame = (function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    var a, b, c;
    function doThis {
        //
    }
    function doThat {
        //
    }

    return function () {
        doThis();
        doThat();  
    }
})(game1, canvas1, onInit);
```

See [more](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) here

EDIT:
Probably you will need to modify your loop also:

```
function loop() {
    updateGame();
    displayGame(game1, canvas2, onInit);
    monitorPreformance(game1, canvas3, onInit);
    onInit = false;
}
setInterval(loop, 20);
```

Comment: This was nearly the solution I was looking for. The see more suggestion allowed me to find my answer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Reading whole book under more link highly recommended.

Comment: Yes it appears to be a good read. Especially as I'm fairly recent to real javascript.